# Not able to call DLL Method in Apache Spark

Tags: java, windows, dll, apache-spark, java-native-interface

I've setup Apache Spark in windows system and have a java program which reads file.txt gets the data and then calls my first.dll file
Now everytime I run it, I get an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due
to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure:
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): 

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:    
main.java.SimpleApp$1$1someClass.SomeJniMethodName(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

Can anyone suggest me why it is failing?
Dll is working fine .. tried and tested with simple Java Application.

Comment: If you are submitting via `spark-submit` and have a multi-node cluster can you confirm all nodes can access to the shared library?

Comment: try adding the DLL under folder pointed to by spark.executor.extraLibraryPath.

Comment: I tried That ... it started working ..